# How did they initially write the system ROM on the Gameboy Advance?

Tags: rom

The GBA has a chip with a arm7tdmi and the ROM (on one chip).
How did they write the software to the ROM?

Pinout is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xa8pN0FXBSJ_yfxgKkc7qfohDGY3Og3I/view?usp=drivesdk)

Edit: question [moved](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25129/is-it-possible-to-alter-the-game-boy-advanve-system-rom)

Comment: Very often a boot rom is "masked" i.e. manufactured in the programmed state.

Comment: You might get better answers to this question on the retrocomputing stackexchange.

Comment: @crasic Yes it's possible. But I need a safe answer.

Comment: why do you want to know how the ROM chips are manufactured?

Comment: @jsotola I want to alter the system ROM with a custom boot up logo. (Yes I know the logo is also stored on the cartridges.)

Comment: why are you not asking that?

Comment: Because when I know the answer to this question I will know how to change it.

Answer (score 2):

We can't know what the correct answer is, as that is likely not public information, and there might be multiple correct answers.

But contrary to what you say, there is no ROM chip for the boot ROM.

The boot ROM contents is built in to the CPU, so it is likely manufactured with the ROM contents.

Comment: Ok sad there is no exact answer. I wanted to overwrite the original software.

Comment: @somega That's a completely different question then. It is not writable or changeable.

Comment: How do you know? A PC's BIOS is also writable.

Comment: @somega That is pretty much the definition of a ROM, that it cannot be written. A modern PC BIOS is usually stored in a flash memory, not ROM. Hence it can be overwritten.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny But Nintendo has also written to it.

Comment: Only because it has the name ROM it doesn't have to be one. If you are familiar with flash storage than you will know that every flash storage is writable. You can read that on Wikipedia where the different flash storage types (e.g. NAND) are explained.

Comment: @somega If you have an example of how Nintendo is able to reprogram it in place, then start by reverse engineering their method, figure out how it works and see if you can replicate it.

Comment: The flash storage is connected to the memory bus and mapped to address 0. I will try to write to that address but I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: @somega ROM can be mask ROM, the bit patterns are manufactured into the MCU, not written. Or if it is written it might be fusible ROM. It does not compare in any way to a PC with Flash ROM, and early PCs also had no means to write ROM. It is likely has no effect if you try to write to ROM address as it would mean any misbehaving program could brick the console by writing to ROM address.

Comment: @Justme Yes I also think writing to that address will fail because of the same reason. Thank you I did not know about mask ROM. But can we be sure it is?

Comment: If it was writable, surely there would already be websites describing how to write it. So it is not writable, or even if it is writable, it is currently unknown how to write it, so either way, you can't write it.